# .NET MVC 3 deployment datetime issue

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, deployment

I try to deploy my .NET MVC Web Application. I have generated the package. When I try to import in IIS with Web Deploy, the SQL script throws a nice error message due to the datetime format of the destination database.
The format in my source database : 23/10/1960 00:00:00

It seems that my production SQLExpress database "culture" is not the same as my dev database
How can I manage this issue ? I really need to keep the data from my dev database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script that creates the database, add the `COLLATE` clause with your explicity collation that you need.  Something like:

```
create database YourDb
....
collate French_CI_AI
```

This will force your explicit collation onto the database to conform to your dev database collation.  This will override the instance collation (or the `model` db collation).

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a good advice. I have created the destination database with visual studio. How can I specify the collation ?

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to keep your dev environment as similar as possible to production, otherwise deployments break, errors can't be reproduced and debugged, etc. Just change the culture on your dev db to match whatever prod has. Here's how: http://www.burch-swm.com/a3.html